# How find substring after substring or between two substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

**string with two substrings:**

```
srt=60389052 - OLGA YANETH PARRA PINILLA8390507 - VICENTE ARROYAVE ARANGO
```

So, I Know how found the first substring (digit + words) and the second:

```
w1 = srt.match (/^\d+\D+)/);  //matches =  60389052 - OLGA YANETH PARRA PINILLA


w2 = srt.match (/\d+\D+$/);   //matches = 8390507 - VICENTE ARROYAVE ARANGO
```

that's fine but if the string are more longer I have problems to match the second substring, for example:

**string with three substrings:**

```
srt=60389052 - OLGA YANETH PARRA PINILLA8390507 - VICENTE ARROYAVE ARANGO777777 GERMAN CASTRO
```

I want to find this:

8390507 - VICENTE ARROYAVE ARANGO

The string sometimes have only two substrings and sometims have three so I have to find always the second one no matter if the string have 2 or 3 substrings, I mean If I use the w2 in the larger string don't match the substring that I want because would find the last substring into three but not the second one.

Comment: are those numbers consistent in length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do global match and get the substring that you need by index (starting from `0`):

```
var matches = str.match(/\d+\D+/g);
console.log(matches[1]);  // "8390507 - VICENTE ARROYAVE ARANGO"
```

Comment: how I can make the index thing inside the match expression?

Comment: console.log(str.match(/\d+\D+/g)[1]); - assuming predictable input

Answer (score 1):

I know the regex is not the most elegant, but since Javascript doesn't support lookbehind, this might not be so bad:

```
str.match(/^\d+\D+\d+\D+/)[0].replace(/^\d+\D+/,'');
```

Also, if you aren't intent on 'match()' - this also is nicer than above:

```
str.replace(/\d+\D+(\d+\D+).*/,'$1');
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
console.log(srt.match(/\d+\D+/g))
```